# Proving $\frac{a}{a^2-a+1}+\frac{b}{b^2-b+1}+\frac{c}{c^2-c+1}+\frac{d}{d^2-d+1}\le \frac{8}{3}$ given $a+b+c+d=2$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a+b+c+d=2$. Prove that $$\frac{a}{a^2-a+1}+\frac{b}{b^2-b+1}+\frac{c}{c^2-c+1}+\frac{d}{d^2-d+1}\le \frac{8}{3}.$$

We have $$\frac{a}{a^2-a+1}\le \frac{4}{3}a\Longleftrightarrow \frac{-a\left(2a-1\right)^2}{3\left(a^2-a+1\right)}\le 0,$$ (Right)

So $$LHS\le \frac{4}{3}\left(a+b+c+d\right)=\frac{8}{3}=RHS$$

When $a=b=c=d=\frac{1}{2}$

But also $a=b=c=1;d=-1$ i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: @Word Please mention what you have already tried.

Comment: $$
f(a,b,c,d)=\frac{1}{\frac{(a-1)^2}{a}+1}+\frac{1}{\frac{(b-1)^2}{b}+1}+\frac{1}{\frac{(c-1)^2}{c}+1}+\frac{1}{\frac{(d-1)^2}{d}+1}
$$

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem, its source, the motivation behind the inequality, and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we simplify a bit by transforming $x = a-\frac12, y = b - \frac12, z = c - \frac12, w = d - \frac12$, so that we need to prove equivalently with $x+y+z+w=0$, the inequality
$$\sum \frac{2x+1}{4x^2+3} \leqslant \frac43$$

Here $\sum$ represents cyclic sums.  Also as $\displaystyle 1 -  2\cdot\frac{2x+1}{4x^2+3} = \frac{(2x-1)^2}{4x^2+3}$, we may equivalently show
$$\sum \frac{(2x-1)^2}{4x^2+3} \geqslant \frac43$$

Now we need an upper bound on the denominator; for this, note

$$4x^2+3=3x^2+(y+z+w)^2+3\leqslant 3x^2+3(y^2+z^2+w^2)+3 = 3\sum x^2+3$$
Thus we have a common denominator now, therefore,
$$\sum \frac{(2x-1)^2}{4x^2+3} \geqslant \frac{\sum (2x-1)^2}{3\sum x^2+3} = \frac{4\sum x^2-4\sum x+4}{3(\sum x^2+1)}=\frac43$$

Comment: $(y+z+w)^2\le 3\left(y^2+z^2+w^2\right)\Leftrightarrow y=z=w$ So we have  $z=x=w,x=y=w,x=y=z\Rightarrow x=y=z=w=1$

Comment: but in that case, the equaLity occur when a=b=c=1,d=-1 and i can't soIve it

Comment: Note the inequality is proven, you are looking for equality cases. In terms of $x,y,z,w$ equality is when $x=y=z=w=0$ and when $x,y,z=\frac12, w=-\frac32$ or permutations. Note in the latter case, numerators become zero, so the bounds on denominators are irrelevant.